# What would be the relationship of my tax and shipping rate models to my stores?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to be able to add tax rates and shipping rates to my `Store` model but I don't know the associations when my plan is to list stores by a particular rate. I plan on giving the rates a date column also in order to keep track of which was what. Is this is a HABTM relationship? What do you think?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to keep track of the rates, then I would do this

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates, :order => 'applied_on desc'
  has_one :actual_rate, :class_name => 'Rate', :order => "applied_on desc"
  scope :with_rate_pc, lambda { |rpc| includes(:rates).where("rates.pourcentage = ?", rpc)}
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Then you could do

```
Store.first.rates #to get all past rates
Store.first.actual_rate #to get the last rate
```

**EDIT**: I Added a scope to `Store` that lets you write:

```
Store.with_rate_pc(7%)
```

Comment: What about if I was to list stores by a certain tax rate? e.g. If Store1 and Store2 had tax rates of 7%?